# sum of two determinant of order 4 by 4

Tags: matrices

if a determinant is a multilinear of its two rows i.e.

> > \begin{vmatrix}a11&a12&a13&a14\\b11&b12&b13&b14\\c11&c12&c13&c14\\d11&d12&d13&d14\end{vmatrix},
> >     \begin{vmatrix}a11&a12&a13&a14\\b11&b12&b13&b14\\e11&e12&e13&e14\\f11&f12&f13&f14\end{vmatrix}
> >
> > then the sum of these two determinants can be written as
> >     \begin{vmatrix}a11&a12&a13&a14\\b11&b12&b13&b14\\c11+e11&c12+e12&c13+e13&c14+e14\\d11+f11&d12+f12&d13+f13&d14+f14\end{vmatrix}
> >     is it right?

Comment: Have you tried it with numbers?  What if both matrices are the identity matrix?

Comment: No, the entries in the determinant are functions of x and t

Comment: The answer is no; the last determinant will be expanded as the sum of 4 determinants, the first 2 you have listed and 2 others.

Comment: then how can we add these two determinants that gives another 4 by 4 determinant

Comment: Why do you think that you can add the two determinants and get a new determinant?

Answer (score 0):

The two by two case, shows enough of what happens in this case:
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}a_1+a_2&b_1+b_2\\c_1+c_2&d_1+d_2\end{bmatrix}=
\det\begin{bmatrix}a_1&b_1\\c_1&d_1\end{bmatrix}
+
\det\begin{bmatrix}a_1&b_1\\c_2&d_2\end{bmatrix}
+
\det\begin{bmatrix}a_2&b_2\\c_1&d_1\end{bmatrix}
+
\det\begin{bmatrix}a_2&b_2\\c_2&d_2\end{bmatrix}.
$$
You can check this because 
\begin{align*}
(a_1+a_2)(d_1+d_2)-(b_1+b_2)(c_1+c_2)&=a_1d_1+a_1d_2+a_2d_1+a_2d_2-b_1c_1-b_1c_2-b_2c_1-b_2c_2\\
&=(a_1d_1-b_1c_1)+(a_1d_2-b_1c_2)+(a_2d_1-b_2c_1)+(a_2d_2-b_2c_2).
\end{align*}

Your situation is very similar.  In particular,
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}&a_{14}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}&a_{24}\\
a_{31}+b_{31}&a_{32}+b_{32}&a_{33}+b_{33}&a_{34}+b_{34}\\
a_{41}+b_{41}&a_{42}+b_{42}&a_{43}+b_{43}&a_{44}+b_{44}
\end{bmatrix}=
\det\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}&a_{14}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}&a_{24}\\
a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}&a_{34}\\
a_{41}+b_{41}&a_{42}+b_{42}&a_{43}+b_{43}&a_{44}+b_{44}
\end{bmatrix}+
\det\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}&a_{14}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}&a_{24}\\
b_{31}&b_{32}&b_{33}&b_{34}\\
a_{41}+b_{41}&a_{42}+b_{42}&a_{43}+b_{43}&a_{44}+b_{44}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}&a_{14}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}&a_{24}\\
a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}&a_{34}\\
a_{41}+b_{41}&a_{42}+b_{42}&a_{43}+b_{43}&a_{44}+b_{44}\end{bmatrix}=\det\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}&a_{14}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}&a_{24}\\
a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}&a_{34}\\
a_{41}&a_{42}&a_{43}&a_{44}
\end{bmatrix}+
\det\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}&a_{14}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}&a_{24}\\
a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}&a_{34}\\
b_{41}&b_{42}&b_{43}&b_{44}\end{bmatrix}
$$
the other matrix expands similarly into a total of four matrices.

Comment: many thanks Michael

Comment: in two by two case, 2nd and 3rd determinants should be $\begin{vmatrix} a_1& \color{red}{b_2}\\ \color{red}{c_1}&d_2\end{vmatrix}$ and $\begin{vmatrix} a_2& \color{red}{b_1}\\ \color{red}{c_2}&d_1\end{vmatrix}$